# iframe ng-attr-srcdoc not working in lower versions of android( 4.3 and below)

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, iframe, ionic-framework

I am using iframe to display my htmlResponse(angularjs embedded html). It is working properly in android versions 4.4 and above. But in lower versions it is not getting rendered. 
This is how i am mentioning iframe in my html

```
<iframe width="100%" height="500px" ng-attr-srcdoc="{{htmlResponse}}"></iframe>
```

Can someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use Webview in android. Use loaddata() in webview.

```
 String doc = "<iframe src='' width='100%' height='100%' style='border: none;'></iframe>";
    webview.loadData(doc, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Hope this helps...